# Is it possible to access a file without opening it in Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive-api

So I currently have an add-on, it works fine. Something I am interested in doing is allowing the user to access the application without entering the document. I know this is possible with the Open With tab once a document is right-clicked but i don't want it sent away from the drive itself if that makes sense. Is there a way to bring up a sidebar within the drive itself once the Open With tab is selected? Or is there another way around this? I essentially just want the user to enter in data that will be assigned to the document but, currently as it's an add-on it only works on google docs files. Would it have to become an app?

Thanks everyone.

Comment: so how do you plan to associate with a specific document?

Comment: Well this is what i'm asking. So let's say a user clicks a doc, and the open with tab comes out. Is it possible to not leave the page? Can the open with tab bring up a script that connects with the doc rather than leaving the drive and bringing it to the third party application

Comment: yes you could make a custom "open with" in apps script and reuse some of your addon code. no you cant do it without leaving the current tab. question is tpo broad to answer well.

Comment: If i send it to the script, where would the open with go?

Comment: the apps script webapp would receive the file id as a parameter.